# Fabric: How to edit file across machines?

Tags: python, devops, fabric

Is there a way to use `Fabric` to open editor and set text?

I have to set new keys on 50+ servers and not willing to do it manually.

Comment: If you have ssh access then you can use rsync to do that. Write a shell script to iterate over ips. And update files

Comment: @crook Can you pls elaborate the `rsync` thing? I was specifically talking about `fabric` tool.

Comment: I don't have Idea about `fabric` tool. `rsync` is a tool which updates file in remote machine if it gets changed in local machine. so you could probably run a for loop over hosts and update files.

Comment: if you give me clear idea where to keep that file in every system then i'll prepare a script for you.

Comment: @crook Nothing to do with local changes. I have to change an `aws` credentials file on many machines.

Comment: Fabric is not really thought for that. But you can use the [scp](https://www.garron.me/en/articles/scp.html) command in a bash script

Answer (score 0):

okay create .aws directory in your local machine and put whatever contents you want to copy.

install `sshpass`

run this command over a loop changing `hostname` and `password`

```
sshpass -p abcpass rsync -arvce "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" ./* user@ip:/home/user/.aws
```